# Help: 'converting 'row number over partition' to 'SIMPLE' sql

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, syntax

PREFACE:
Hi, I'm studying SQL, I haven't been taught about partitioning with this feature, so I'd like to understand how to solve this problem using 'basic' SQL statements.

My relation is like this:

> Table (employee, day, worked_hours)

I have to get the 5 days each employee worked longer, this for each employee **(each day may have more than 1 record per employee)**

the solution I found (but that won't be accepted at the exam) is this:

```
SELECT t.employee, t.day, t.w_hour
FROM ( 
       SELECT employee, day, w_hour
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee 
                          ORDER BY w_hour DESC, day DESC) AS rn
       FROM table
     ) AS t
WHERE T.rn <=5
```

Comment: The query you have doesn't look correct. I think it should be `OVER (PARTITION BY employee ORDER BY w_hour DESC)`

Comment: As for the actual issue, what do you want to happen with ties? (eg, 3 days tied at position 4)? Should all be in the result? Or only two of them?

Comment: Thanks for the correction, ties should be kept in the report BUT, as this is a learning issue, may also be considered later. My first point is to understand the 'main' principle (partitioning), only after refining it.

Comment: Last question: I noticed you say that "each day may have more than 1 record per employee". What does that mean? If an employee has a day with 7-hours and another  with two 4-hours rows, is the maximum 7 or 8 (the sum of 4+4)? In other words, should the two 4-hours rows count as two records or as one (with 8-hours)?

Comment: A employee may have worked on the same day 5 hours in the morning and 3 in the afternoon leading to two entries. Ex: [day: 7, emp: 002, hours: 5], [day: 7, emp: 002, hours: 3]. In the final report I should have [emp: 002, day: 7, hours: 8], if this is one of the top-5 days for emp 002

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, according to clarifications, the query you have is not correct. You need to first sum (per day and employee) and then `ORDER BY SUM(w_hour) DESC` in the window. The query becomes:

```
SELECT employee, day, sum_w_hour
FROM ( 
       SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee 
                              ORDER BY SUM(w_hour) DESC) AS rn
       FROM table
       GROUP BY employee, day
     ) AS t
WHERE rn <= 5 ;
```

Also note that the above does not consider ties. If there are (ties), it will choose arbitrarily and return only 5 results per employee. If you want all tied results, use a different ranking function: `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Now, to write the query without "complex SQL", i.e. without window/ranking functions and without `LATERAL` joins (called `CROSS / OUTER APPLY` in SQL Server), one way would be to use a correlated subquery and `COUNT()`.
Note how we have the same derived table used twice (named `t` and `b`):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    ( SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour
      FROM table
      GROUP BY employee, day 
    ) AS t
WHERE
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM 
          ( SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour
            FROM table
            GROUP BY employee, day 
          ) AS b
      WHERE b.employee = t.employee
        AND b.sum_w_hour > t.sum_w_hour
    ) < 5 ;
```

which can be simplified a bit (although it's not more clear in my opinion):

```
SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour
FROM table AS t
GROUP BY employee, day 
HAVING 
    ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM 
          ( SELECT 1
            FROM table
            WHERE employee = t.employee
            GROUP BY employee, day 
            HAVING SUM(w_hour) > SUM(t.w_hour)
          ) AS c
    ) < 5 ;
```

And yet another way would be self-join the table (or rather the derived table after aggregation) and `GROUP BY - COUNT`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    ( SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour
      FROM work
      GROUP BY employee, day 
    ) AS t
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT employee, day, SUM(w_hour) AS sum_w_hour
      FROM work
      GROUP BY employee, day 
    ) AS b
  ON  b.employee = t.employee
  AND b.sum_w_hour > t.sum_w_hour
GROUP BY
    t.employee, t.day, t.sum_w_hour
HAVING 
    COUNT(b.day) < 5 ;
```

All the "simple SQL" queries above can be described with:

> Show me for each employee all days where there are less than 5 other days that the same employee has higher sum of work hours.

Tested in: **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=11e35b703a46e184a864bdb3fa96c346)**

<sup>Note: the queries that use the same derived table twice could be simplified using CTEs (Common Table Expressions) but I suppose that is consider "complex SQL", too.</sup>